# Storyboard doesn't animate custom FrameworkElement property

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have class that is derived from `FrameworkElement`, and I want WPF to update its Location property by using `DoubleAnimation`. I register the property as `DependendencyProperty`:

```
public class TimeCursor : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationProperty;

    public double Location
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LocationProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LocationProperty, value);
        }
    }

    static TimeCursor()
    {
        LocationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Location", typeof(double), typeof(TimeCursor));
    }
}
```

Following code sets up the storyboard.

```
TimeCursor timeCursor;
private void SetCursorAnimation()
{
    timeCursor = new TimeCursor();
    NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
    RegisterName("TimeCursor", timeCursor);

    storyboard.Children.Clear();

    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(LeftOffset, LeftOffset + (VerticalLineCount - 1) * HorizontalGap + VerticalLineThickness, 
                new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(musicDuration)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "TimeCursor");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(TimeCursor.LocationProperty));

    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
}
```

Then I call `storyboard.Begin(this)` from another method of the object which contains the above `SetCursorAnimation()` method and this object is derived from `Canvas`. However the `Location` property is never updated(set accessor of Location is never called) and no exception is thrown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a dependency property is animated (or set in XAML, or set by a Style Setter, etc.), WPF does not call the CLR wrapper, but instead directly accesses the underlying DependencyObject and DependencyProperty objects. See the *Implementing the "Wrapper"* section in [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist) and also [Implications for Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx#implications).

In order to get notified about property changes, you have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx):

```
public class TimeCursor : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Location", typeof(double), typeof(TimeCursor),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(LocationPropertyChanged)); // register callback here

    public double Location
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LocationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LocationProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void LocationPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var timeCursor = obj as TimeCursor;

        // handle Location property changes here
        ...
    }
}
```

---

And note also that animating a dependency property does not necessarily require a Storyboard. You could simply call the [BeginAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598906.aspx) method on your TimeCursor instance:

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation(LeftOffset,
    LeftOffset + (VerticalLineCount - 1) * HorizontalGap + VerticalLineThickness, 
    new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(musicDuration)),
    FillBehavior.HoldEnd);

timeCursor.BeginAnimation(TimeCursor.LocationProperty, animation);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works the way you suggested. I have to use a storyboard because I also need to pause the animation.